# Android - What to use in place of AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent because its deprecated

Tags: android, android-account

I am working on a project where I have to show the account chooser so that a user can select an email account which is stored in his device. Problem is I have got `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent` which is deprecated.

> Is there any alternate way to show the account chooser instead of
>   getting the email manually, and showing it in a custom view

Right now I am using:

```
Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
        new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, true, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it will be helpful to someone, in 2020 use this according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker?hl=ru#newChooseAccountIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker.AccountChooserOptions)):

```
Intent intent =
 AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(
     new AccountChooserOptions.Builder()
         .setAllowableAccountsTypes(Arrays.asList("com.google"))
         .build());

startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Also you can use [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle)):

```
Intent intent;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                        new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, null, null, null, null);
} else {
    intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                        new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, false, null, null, null, null);
}

startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

You can get selected email from **authAccount** extra:

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode,
                                    final Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            // Do what you need with email 
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [developers' documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle)):

Adding `alwaysPromptForAccount` boolean value as an argument to the `newChooseAccountIntent` is now deprecated. The new method is now written as follows:

`newChooseAccountIntent(Account, List, String[], String, String, String[], Bundle)`.

So now in your case, your code will look like this:

```
Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, null, null, null, null); 
startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depreciation doesn't mean you can't use it. Google will keep the code in their android os since that some apps are so ancient they still use depreciated code.

Comment: But you have to be at safer side and there always be an alternate methods for deprecated methods.

Comment: That is true. Some depreciated methods are tougher to implement, but i'd rather take tougher than use a different sdk on Eclipse. We all know how much of a hassle Android Studio is, and the fact that it makes apks much more bulkier than their Eclipse counter.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker):

> Common account picker similar to the standard framework account picker
>   introduced in ICS: newChooseAccountIntent().

So you can use [newChooseAccountIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle)) method available in [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class. It has the same inputs and output.